# How to check specific element presence of element in an array in smarty?

Tags: arrays, if-statement, smarty

I'm assigning one array from PHP to smarty template as follows:

```
$smarty->assign('data', $contact_list_user_data);
```

The array looks like following:

```
Array
(
    [op] => import
    [contact_list_id] => 9
    [form_submitted] => yes
    [cl_user_type] => Array
        (
            [0] => upload_from_file
            [1] => copy_paste_from_excel
        )

    [registered_users_from_date] => 
    [registered_users_to_date] => 
    [logged_in_users_from_date] => 
    [logged_in_users_to_date] => 
    [not_logged_in_users_from_date] => 
    [not_logged_in_users_to_date] => 
    [test_pack_type_id] => 
    [submit_value] => Submit
)
```

Now on a form in smarty template I want to make the specific checkbox checked if the matching value is find. But I'm not able to parse the array in right manner. In short I want to the checkbox to be selected if the values from subarray `cl_user_type` gets mathed with the values of the checkboxes present in the form. In above case I want the last two checkboxes to be selected. How should I write if condition for this in smarty? Could you please help me in achieving this. I tried with the if in first condition but couldn't succeed. 
The code from smarty template is as follows:

```
<tr height="30" id="user_option">
                    <td width="300">
                       <input type="checkbox" id="users" name="cl_user_type[]" value="users" {if $data.cl_user_type=='users'}checked="checked"{/if}/>Users 
                    </td>
                    <td>&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" id="upload_from_file" name="cl_user_type[]" value="upload_from_file" />Upload From File
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="copy_paste_from_excel" name="cl_user_type[]" value="copy_paste_from_excel"/>Copy paste from excel
                    </td>
                  </tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried smarty {[html_checkboxes](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.html.checkboxes.tpl)}? If for some reason you can't use it, there are two solutions, being the better one modifiying the cl_user_type array before sending it to smarty like this:

```
[cl_user_type] => Array
    (
        [upload_from_file] => true,
        [copy_paste_from_excel] =>true
    )
```

and then in your smarty code:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="upload_from_file" name="cl_user_type[]" value="upload_from_file" {if $data.cl_user_type.upload_from_file}checked="checked"{/if}/>
```

the other (worse) option, using a foreach for every checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="upload_from_file" name="cl_user_type[]" value="upload_from_file"   
    {foreach $data.cl_user_type as $type}
      {if $type=='upload_from_file'}checked="checked"{/if}
    {/foreach}
    />
```

as a sidenote, I would recommend you using a variable so you can easily duplicate checkboxes for different user types. The first solution would look like this:

```
{$user_type = 'copy_paste_from_excel'}
 <input type="checkbox" id="{$user_type}" name="cl_user_type[]" value="{$user_type}" {if $data.cl_user_type.$user_type}checked="checked"{/if}/>
```